# Dynamic Property and Child Model Not Binding

Tags: .net-core, blazor

I want to build dynamic form using Blazor.

Here is my sample component.

```
    @page "/customform"

    @using System.Dynamic
    @using System.Text.Json
 
    @inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime;

    <div class="card m-3">
    <h4 class="card-header">Blazor WebAssembly Form Validation Example</h4>
    <div class="card-body">
        <EditForm EditContext="@editContext"
                  OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit">
            <DataAnnotationsValidator></DataAnnotationsValidator>
           
            @foreach (var field in Model.Fields)
        {

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>@field.Name</label>
                <input @bind-value="field.Value" class="form-control" />
                <ValidationMessage For="(()=> field.Value)" />
                <ValidationMessage For="(()=> field.Name)" />
                <ValidationMessage For="(()=> field)" />

            </div>

        }
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Address</label>
                <input @bind-value="Model.Address" class="form-control" />
                <ValidationMessage For="()=> Model.Address" />

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Child</label>
                <input @bind-value="Model.ChildModel.ChildName" class="form-control" />
                <ValidationMessage For="()=> Model.ChildModel.ChildName" />

            </div>
            <div class="text-left">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>

        </EditForm>
    </div>
         </div>

      @code{

    private SampleModel Model = new SampleModel();
    private EditContext editContext;
    private ValidationMessageStore _messageStore;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {

        editContext = new EditContext(Model);
        editContext.OnValidationRequested += ValidationRequested;
        _messageStore = new ValidationMessageStore(editContext);      
    }

    private void HandleValidSubmit(EditContext context)
    {
        var modelJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(context.Model, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true });
        JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("alert", $"SUCCESS!! :-)\n\n{modelJson}");
       
    }

    async void ValidationRequested(object sender, ValidationRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        _messageStore.Add(editContext.Field("FirstName"), "Test");
        _messageStore.Add(editContext.Field("Address"), "Invalid Address");
        _messageStore.Add(editContext.Field("ChildModel.ChildName"), "Invalid Child Name");
        editContext.NotifyValidationStateChanged();
    }

    

    public class SampleModel
    {

        public string Address { get; set; }

        public ChildModel ChildModel { get; set; }
        public List<Field> Fields { get; set; }
        public SampleModel()
        {
            this.ChildModel = new ChildModel();
            this.Fields = new List<Field>();
            this.Fields.Add(new Field()
            {
                Name = "FirstName",
                Value = "",
                ControlType = ControlType.Input
            });
            this.Fields.Add(new Field()
            {
                Name = "LastName",
                Value = "",
                ControlType = ControlType.Input
            });
        }
    }

    public class ChildModel
    {
        public string ChildName { get; set; }
    }

    public enum ControlType
    {
        Input
    }

    public class Field
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public ControlType ControlType { get; set; }


    }

    
}
```

Currently I am facing too many issues.

1. If I use For lookup instead of For each it is not working
2. ChildModel seems to be bind but its validation is not working
3. Dynamically generated based on Fields collection control does not display validation.
4. Only address in SimpleModel display validation.

Is there any suggestion or help around this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your profile suggests you know what you're doing, so I'll keep this succinct.

Your `for` loop needs to look something like this.  Set a local "index" variable within the loop to link the controls to.  If you don't they point to the last value of `i` - in this case 2 which is `out of range`!  The razor code is converted to a cs file by the razor builder.  You can see the c# file generated in the *obj* folder structure - *obj\Debug\net5.0\Razor\Pages*.  Note, the linkage of the Validation Message

```cs
@for(var i = 0; i < Model.Fields.Count; i++)
   {
    var index = i;
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>@Model.Fields[index].Name</label>
      <input @bind-value="Model.Fields[index].Value" class="form-control" />
      <ValidationMessage For="(()=> Model.Fields[index].Value)" />
    </div>
}
```

Now the message validation store.  Here's my rewritten `ValidationRequested`.  Note I'm creating a `FieldIdentifier` which is the correct way to do it. "Address" works because it's a property of `EditContext.Model`.  If a `ValidationMessage` doesn't display the message you anticipate, then it's either not being generated, or it's `FieldIdentifier` doesn't match the field the `ValidationMessage` is `For`.   This should get you going in whatever project you're involved in - if not add a comment for clarification :-).

```cs
    void ValidationRequested(object sender, ValidationRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        _messageStore.Clear();
        _messageStore.Add(new FieldIdentifier(Model.Fields[0], "Value"), "FirstName Validation Message");
        _messageStore.Add(new FieldIdentifier(Model.Fields[1], "Value"), "Surname Validation Message");
        _messageStore.Add(editContext.Field("FirstName"), "Test");
        _messageStore.Add(editContext.Field("Address"), "Invalid Address");
        _messageStore.Add(editContext.Field("ChildModel.ChildName"), "Invalid Child Name");
        editContext.NotifyValidationStateChanged();
    }
```

If you interested in Validation and want something more that the basic out-of-the-box validation, there's a couple of my articles that might give you info [Validation Form State Control](https://shauncurtis.github.io/articles/ValidationFormState.html) or there's a  version of Fluent Validation by Chris Sainty out there if you search.

Comment: I can see from your profile that you like donating:};} Please see my profile... there is a link for donation ;}

Comment: Yes, old and grey (and locked down!) these days. Answering questions for fun - Beats doing the crossword and puzzles in the paper!